# How to build an Expo application on Linux locally

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, expo

I've tried to build my application using [EAS](https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/)

```
eas build --platform android --local
```

It keeps giving me errors that make no sense.
How can I install the compatible SDK versions and gradle?

I've tried to do `eas build --platform android --local`

I was expecting to get an Android application bundle / apk